# Code Review: is this following rxjs principle?

Tags: rxjs

I'm pretty new to reactive programming and I'd like to get your opinion on a short code snippet to see how far I am from the Rx way of thinking.

My purpose is to get about 2245 items from a web service which returns maximum 500 items a time. So I have to make several calls and concatenate all the results.

I store all the promises returned by $.getJSON in an array and then use the forkJoin method to process the results all together.

```
// get the exact total number of items
function getCount() {
    return $.get({
        url: '/sites/_api/items/count',
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" }
    });
}

getCount().done(function (result) {
    var promises = []; // store promises
    var total = result.d.ItemCount; // total number of items
    var batch = 500; // number of items to fetch for each request
    var count = Math.ceil(total / batch); // number of request needed

    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        var skip = batch * i; // number of item already fetched
        var top = batch * (i + 1) > total ? (total % batch) : batch; // number of item to fetch
        var p = $.getJSON("/sites/_api/items?$select=" + fieldname + "&$skip=" + skip + "&$top=" + top); // get promise
        promises.push(p); // store promise in dedicated array
    }

    // join all promises and handle all results at once
    Rx.Observable.forkJoin(promises).subscribe(function (result) {
        console.log(result); //[object, object, object, object, object]
    });

});
```

This gives me the expected result, but I would like to get your opinion if there's any better way to do this using Rx.

------ EDIT ---------
I'm adding the code of a first attempt which was based on the stream concept. Meaning I have an unknown number of request to issue. I'll add up the result as they come (see function onDataReceived) and handle them as a whole when finished. Except I could not find out how to notify that all the request have been completed and trigger the 'completed' method of the observable.

```js
var items = [];
var obs;


function onDataReceived(data) {
    obs.onNext(data);
}

function getFieldValue(fieldname, skip, top) {
    var uri = "/sites/_api/items?&$skip=" + skip + "&$top=" + top;
    $.getJSON(uri, onDataReceived);
}

function getCount() {
    return $.get({
        url: '/sites/_api/items/count',
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" }
    });
}


   
obs = new Rx.Subject();

obs.subscribe(
    function (value) { items = items.concat(value.d); },
    function (err) {  console.err(err); },
    function () { console.log("completed" + items.length); }
);


getCount().done(function (result) {
    var total = result.d.ItemCount;     
    var batch = 500;
    var count = Math.ceil(total / batch);
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        var skip = batch * i;
        var top = batch * (i + 1) > total ? (total % batch) - 1 : batch;
        getFieldValue(skip, top);
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not taking benefit of all that Rx provides but merely is changing its interface to Observable. It is still internally promises all the way.

Promises are eager so invoking `$_json()` will immediately start fetching data. If possible push as much promises out of your code or at least wrap them with `Rx.Observable.defer()`

Try to make your function return a lazy Observable which only upon `.subscribe` starts running see below example implementation which includes throttling (10 concurrent requests to API for page details)

```js
function mock_get_count() {
  return Rx.Observable.of(255)
    .delay(500)
    .toPromise(); // to mock $.get() signature (returning promise)
}

function mock_get_page(page) {
  return Rx.Observable.of('')
    .do(() => console.log('starting page ' + page))
    .ignoreElements()
    .concat(
      Rx.Observable.range(10 * page, 10)
        .toArray()
        .delay(1000 + Math.random() * 2000) /* slow api, response takes 1-3 seconds*/
    )
    .toPromise() /* to mock your $.JSON() signature (returning promise) */
  ;
}

function getAllResults() {
  return Rx.Observable.defer(() => mock_get_count())
    .mergeMap(itemCount => {
      const pages = Math.ceil(itemCount / 10);
      console.log('itemCount: ' + itemCount + ', pages: ' + pages);
    
      return Rx.Observable.range(0, pages)
        .mergeMap(
          p => Rx.Observable.defer(() => mock_get_page(p)),
          null, 
          10 /* concurrent requests to API */
        );
    })
}

getAllResults().subscribe(console.log)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.1.0/Rx.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand the benefit of lazy loading though this is not really an issue for me here since I have to do those requests anyway. My concern was more that I have an unknown number of request and I need to handle the result as whole when they are all completed. I turned toward RxJS because I could really see this a stream. I've edit my original post to add the code of a first attempt which was based on the stream "pattern" except I could not find out how to notice all the request were completed and trigger the "completed" method of the observable...

Comment: Hi Julien, please see my revised answer with a Rx version of your issue. Lazy loading is **exactly** what you need since you have _an unknown number of requests_. You need to throttle those. You can still stream your results using Rx.